# List of errors when archiving project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In an attempt to archive my app for publishing (on a Windows machine), I was given an error that basically (from what I found on the internet) told me to update visual studio (From 16.5.4 I think to 16.7.6). After doing so, I receive build errors telling me to "You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for (project).Android" (From version 9.0 to version 10.0. However, when I change the Target Framework I get a list of errors "assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Support.[v7.RecyclerView, vector.Drawable, v4, Animated.Vector.Drawable, v7.AppCompat, Design]' is using '[assembly: (Java.InteropJavaLibraryReferenceAttribute or Android.IncludeAndroidResourcesFromAttribute)]' Use a newer version of this NuGet package or notify the library author." But when I go to update, there is nothing to update (as I've updated every package already).

I'm not sure what to do with this issue. Any advice would be greatly helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd better not updating the nuget packages one by one.

We can select the option that **Select all packages** to update all one time, then the conflict error between them will not occur.

[image]

**Now** you could restore the previous version of each updated nuget packages, then have a try with my shared ways.

Answer (score 0):

The build errors that you are seeing now are because you updated the targetVersione from 9-10 without updating to AndroidX Nuget packages.

This [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/android-10-requirements/?ocid=3017126) will guide you how to update the targetVersion from 9-10 and the possible erros that might occur during the update.

This [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/androidx-nuget-packages-are-stable/?WT.mc_id=androidreq-blog-jamont) which is inside the first post will guide how to do the update automatically.